# Set variable as sheet name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want the variable "sheetname" to be the name of the active sheet.
How do I do this? I tried

```
    var sheetname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName();
```

But it did not work. 
Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `Sheet.getName()`, check the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getName%28%29).

```
var sheetname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
```

The `.getName()` method exists in both Spreadsheet and Sheet classes. `Spreadsheet.getName()` will return the name of the *document*, while `Sheet.getName()` will give you the name of the sheet within a spreadsheet (the same name that appears on the "tab"). In Google Apps Script, as with javascript, you need to pay attention to the return types of method or function calls to make sure you're invoking the right method in a chain.

In your example, `.getActiveSpreadsheet()` returns a Spreadsheet instance. In the re-write, we use `.getActiveSheet()` instead, yielding a Sheet.

Comment: thanks for the thorough explanation! i needed to use $sheetname, then it worked!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working if you have multiple sheets. On Sheet2, this still returns "Sheet1".

Comment: @10basetom - [Here's a demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zg-FU3KEGq-IgHGRpv4ETTqXGQRvJFbUXqzsYFup7Wg/edit?usp=sharing), take a copy of the spreadsheet and try it yourself. Navigate to any sheet, and run "Sheet Name > Show Sheet Name". Works just fine. If you're having a problem, raise a question with details about your code (e.g. is it a trigger function, an embedded script, etc.).

Comment: @Mogsdad Thanks for the demo sheet, but do you have a solution that doesn't show the "Request for Permission" popup window? I'm trying to create a custom function that can be used in any cell (e.g., =sheetName()) that outputs the correct sheet name without asking for permissions.

Comment: _That's_ why I asked for more info! In a custom function, there's no concept of the "active" spreadsheet, so `.getActiveSheet()` always defaults to the first sheet, and `.getActiveRange()` is always `A1`. Any function that CAN access these details will require authorization - no way around that.